# Mocking gps locations in phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova, gps

I'm relatively new to Phonegap and I would like to know if there is a way to mock gps location on a android device using it or if using the Location class in android is the only way to do it?

Comment: Any working code that can be shared here ?

Comment: Location services in android -                                 `Double lat = Double.valueOf(MockLoc[0]);
location.setLatitude(lat);
Double longi = Double.valueOf(MockLoc[1]);
location.setLongitude(longi);`                                         I dont know something like that for Phonegap

Comment: what do you want? User Current Location or Something else.

Comment: I have to mock user's current location through phonegap

Comment: Did you ever find out if this is possible?

Comment: I remember seeing a github project where you can communicate the location(long,lat) to the app over tcp and it will mock it. I'll give the link if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below:

http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~cmg/G54UBI/coursework2/GPS_and_Maps.html

> 1. Getting GPS position
>
>    Using the location sensor in AppInventor:
>      http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/appinventor/locationsensor.html
>
>    Using GPS in JavaScript, including PhoneGap:
>      http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation
>      Note the "quirk" at the bottom, i.e. to get mock GPS on the emulator you must set the option 
>      "enableHighAccuracy" to "true".
>
>    It appears that there is a problem with mock locations on the Android 2.3.3 emulator (it seems to
>      crash/reboot the emulator). Please avoid using this version of the emulator; try Android 2.2 instead.